# iPad: Correct approach to custom navigation items in UINavigationController

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller, customization, uibarbuttonitem

This relates to a question I asked a few days ago: [iOS: Setting text in nib subview from view in UITabBar/UINavigationController application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020222/ios-setting-text-in-nib-subview-from-view-in-uitabbar-uinavigationcontroller-app)

I need to put the search bar and buttons on the top right of a navigation controller, this is more than the standard single button that UINavigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem allows so I am using the initWithCustomView: method of UIBarButtonItem to load a view from a nib file.

In my particular case, i've put the view as a seperate item in the main view file for that form

The problem i've got is load and display sequence and I wanted to know if this was the right approach to this?

It seems that the following happens:

viewDidLoad on my main window gets called
viewDidAppear on my main window gets called and I set up rightBarButtonItem
I then want to populate a text field on that search bar but because the loading of the view for the button item happens in the main thread, I don't know when it's appeared.

Would I be better to create a new class with nib for the search bar and buttons which would then have a viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear and I could then create a delegate function so I could 'deQueue' the text to go into the search bar?

Or, am I missing something really simple?

Comment: I figured this out, see the other post for an explanation or read the example here: http://www.jamesrbrindle.com/developer/ios-developer/howto-add-a-custom-uinavigationitem-to-a-uinavigationcontroller-with-delegation.htm

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept as an answer.